# WPF RibbonTab binding to DataContext of Ribbon

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to bind to the RibbonTab parent in a datatemplate of the header like this :

```
<ribbon:RibbonTab.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ribbon:RibbonTab}}}" Margin="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ribbon:RibbonTab.HeaderTemplate>
```

I want to get to the point where the viewmodelname that is behind the ribbontab would display in the textblock. Once the name pops up there I know how to get to the properties of the viewmodel. But if the viewmodelname does not show I suspect the binding is not ok.

How should I do this ? The above does not work apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `x:Name` on ribbonTab and bind it using `ElementName`. This should work:

```
<ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="MyTab">
    <ribbon:RibbonTab.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=MyTab}"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
    </ribbon:RibbonTab.HeaderTemplate>
</ribbon:RibbonTab>
```

RelativeSource won't work because RibbonTab doesn't lies in same VisualTree as that of HeaderTemplate.

---

Also you can use `x:Reference` to make it work.

```
<ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="MyTab">
    <ribbon:RibbonTab.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext, Source={x:Reference MyTab}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
    </ribbon:RibbonTab.HeaderTemplate>
</ribbon:RibbonTab>
```

Comment: In the debug window i find following string : System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=MyTab'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Strange worked for me in small sample I just tried. Are you using `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` control? Have you set `x:Name` correctly to `MyTab` on RibbonTab control?